# Logging to windows event using Pantheios logging library

Tags: logging, pantheios

> How can i send log messages to windows event log using Pantheios?

and

> If i do it from multiple process using Pantheious , will it be process
>   safe? Will i get craches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use be.WindowsEventLog.
2. No, I don't believe so, any more than you would using Event Log from multiple processes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do the following:

1. You need to link with be.WindowsEventLog.
   On Windows this can be done with implicit linking by adding `#include <pantheios/implicit_link/be.WindowsEventLog.h>` to one of your compilation units.
2. Also, you *must* define the application specific function [`pantheios_be_WindowsEventLog_calcCategoryAndEventId()`](http://www.pantheios.org/doc/html/group__group____backend____stock__backends____WindowsEventLog.html#g761e2b97e66b949cead54131f7523666) (as specified in the *tiny* note in the [docs](http://www.pantheios.org/doc/html/group__group____backend____stock__backends____WindowsEventLog.html#g761e2b97e66b949cead54131f7523666): ***Note*** This is an application-specified function..

An example, bare-simple implementation can be found in `pantheios-folder\test\scratch\test.scratch.api\test.scratch.api.cpp`:

```
//  The following allows this to be used with the Windows EventLog back-end.
PANTHEIOS_CALL(void) pantheios_be_WindowsEventLog_calcCategoryAndEventId(
    int                     /* backEndId */
,   int                     /* severity */
,   pantheios::uint16_t*    category 
,   pantheios::uint32_t*    eventId
) /* throw() */
{

   // NOTE: A proper implementation would specify non-0 values here that
   // identify the requisite event identifier and category within the
   // associated message file(s).

   *eventId    =   0;
   *category   =   0;
}
```

Documentation for `category` and `eventID` can be found on the [MSDN Event Logging docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) respectively.